# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs code runs but fails to save the workbook

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I run the code, it asks if I want to save the workbook to the location, I click yes, and then the code ends. I check the folder, the file isn't saved there. I am posting the relevant sections of code here. Note, there are other variables, and code sections that I have not included here. I am working up towards assigning this to a command button on one of the sheets, and want to eventually have the No answer to lead to the next step in the process where sections of multiple sheets will be saved to a PDF and then print those same reports. I have further issues on that but once I resolve this immediate pressing issue, I'll come back if I can't fix the other one.

```
Sub mac_CreateProposalFolder()

    Dim varFilePathDir As Range
    Set varFilePathDir = Range("cell_FilePathDrive")

    Dim varFilePathProjYear As Range
    Set varFilePathProjYear = Range("cell_FilePathYear")

    Dim varFilePathProjYNum As Range
    Set varFilePathProjYNum = Range("cell_FilePathYearSuffix")

    Dim varFilePathProjName As Range
    Set varFilePathProjName = Range("cell_DDGJobName")

    Dim varFilePathSubFold1 As Range
    Set varFilePathSubFold1 = Range("cell_FilePathSubFolder1")

    Dim varBusinessUnit As Range
    Set varBusinessUnit = Range("cell_BusinessUnit")

    Dim varDDGJobNumber As Range
    Set varDDGJobNumber = Range("cell_DDGJobNumber")

    Dim varProposalDate As Range
    Set varProposalDate = Range("cell_ProposalDate")

    Dim varFilePathSaveAs1Survey As String
    Dim varFilePath1Survey As String

    Dim varAnswer5Survey As VbMsgBoxResult

    varFilePath1Survey = varFilePathDir & varFilePathProjYear & "-000\" & varFilePathProjYear & varFilePathProjYNum & " " & varFilePathProjName
    
    varFilePathSaveAs1Survey = varFilePath1Survey & "\" & varFilePathSubFold1 & "\" & varBusinessUnit & " Proposal for " & varDDGJobNumber & " " & varFilePathProjName & " on " & varProposalDate
    
        'Checks if the proposal file has been created for this project and asks if the user wishes to save the file if not, or cancel the operation.
        If VBA.FileSystem.Dir(varFilePathSaveAs1Survey) = vbNullString Then
            varAnswer5Survey = MsgBox("Excel file for this business unit and proposal date has not been saved to this folder yet. Do you wish to save this excel file to the folder?", vbYesNoCancel, "Save Excel Workbook?")
            Select Case varAnswer5Survey
                Case vbYes
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=varFilePathSaveAs1Survey & ".xlsm"
                Case vbNo
                    'saved spot for future code options.
                    Exit Sub
                Case vbCancel
                    Exit Sub
            End Select
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

I have attempted multiple methods for the save as - using `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` in place of `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` (preference is 'Active' not 'This' because the workbook will be a generic one that gets saved to the folder as the active one for this project and this date);

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ([varFilePathSaveAs1Survey & ".xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled]); 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= varFilePathSaveAs1Survey & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled; ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ([Filename:= varFilePathSaveAs1Survey & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled])
```

and multiple other configurations. I even recorded a macro and copied the text from that one while altering the desktop location for saving the macro to the preferred location:

```
    ChDir "C:\Users\******\OneDrive - **********, PC\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "https://******-
my.sharepoint.com/personal/******/Documents/Desktop/PROJECT%20BUDGET-Rough%20Draft%20V1.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Note: ***** are scrubbed sections of links due to safeguarding internal information.

So far, all the typical methods recommended have not worked and while the code compiles, it just won't save.

I am using Windows 11 on a Dell Precision, Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302....64 bit)

Edit: solution to the issue lay in the date formatting - the cell had it formatted in "YYYY-MM-DD" but the code was reading it as mm\dd\yyyy and it was erroring due to attempting to find a mm directory, then dd directory, then yyyy directory. Changing the date format fixed the error.

Comment: just an fyi, putting `On Error Resume Next` at the end of the code does nothing.  When that is used, any code AFTER it will be skipped if an error in that line happens.  Since it is the last line there is no code after to skip on error.

Comment: After the save if you add `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FullName` what do you see?

Comment: Apologies, didn't expect such quick responses and went to lunch just after submitting. I get almost everything correct, although the date is not formatted correctly. The date is coming through as 3\4\2023. Okay, in solving that issue it finally saved, but now when I change the code for the date to read Format(varProposalDate, YYYY - MM - DD) it is returning 44989 in the save file.

Comment: `Format(varProposalDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")` do not forget the quotes.  It requires a string.

Comment: Thank you. The code is functional now and doing what it is supposed to be doing. This is my first time using Stack Overflow from this side and not just looking for answers - what is the appropriate method for noting who solved the issue - Tim Williams gave me the method I needed for determining what was wrong and set me on the path to solving it, but you, Scott, helped me save the file in the format I needed...

Comment: It takes a village!

Comment: Well, I'd love to mark either of you as having answered my question but I don't have any green checkmarks next to either of your names in order to mark the answer as accepted. I waited the 15+ minutes for newbies and it still isn't showing so I'll just say thanks to the both of you! I edited my comment to show it complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get any error on saving but the file isn't where you expect, then

```
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

immediately after calling `SaveAs` will show you where the workbook actually got saved.  That may help you fix your code.

From Scott

```
Format(varProposalDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

will give you the date in a format that useable in a file path or file name.